# Get timeline from my facebook page and pull in my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to get my facebook posts and add them to my web site, I was able to do with pages without any problems, in this way.

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/pagehere/posts?access_token=tokenhere

I have a code in javascript that gets my posts, however the user who is browsing my site does not see the posts, only I see and I have to be logged with my facebook. this method is more for login with facebook.

[Código](https://github.com/bradtraversy/socialauth)

I've already done those steps.

[Graph API Explorer:](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?v=gXux8b3wcYw&redir_token=vCPMhMWCin-IUVN_cIlqT2hgzNZ8MTUyODY2NzIwNUAxNTI4NTgwODA1&event=video_description&q=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer%2F)

[Register Facebook App:](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?v=gXux8b3wcYw&redir_token=vCPMhMWCin-IUVN_cIlqT2hgzNZ8MTUyODY2NzIwNUAxNTI4NTgwODA1&event=video_description&q=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fapps%2F)

Comment: your app is in dev mode, i guess. that´s why.

Comment: luschn, yessss.

Answer (score 0):

Posts do not show up when they were made with an App in developer mode. You need to make the App public in the App settings.